# This code will never be executed warning swift equatable enum

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code from a 3rd party library:

```
public enum NoError: Swift.Error, Equatable {
    public static func ==(lhs: NoError, rhs: NoError) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

This generates the warning :
1. 'lhs' is uninhabited, so this function body can never be executed
This will never be executed

How could I get rid of this warning?

Comment: It is impossible to instantiate a value of the `NoError` type, because the enumeration has *no cases.*

Comment: Is this the fix that you are looking for https://github.com/antitypical/Result/blob/master/Result/NoError.swift ?

Comment: yes that is the library generating the warning

Comment: And the answer to this question is in that link in case you didn't notice.

Comment: @MartinR answer should be the way to go. However it does not get rid of the warning for me... Xcode 11.4

Answer (score 4):

`enum` should have `case`. I mean enumeration should have definition. I don't understand why `enum` uses here, because it's can be `class`. However, this will work without warnings:

```
public enum NoError: Swift.Error, Equatable {

    case case1
    case case2

    public static func ==(lhs: NoError, rhs: NoError) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a 3rd party library so it might be a littler hard to change the code